# Flex 4 - How to store image data into variable or object

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

My coding,

```
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var loadFile:FileReference;
        protected function browseButtonClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            loadFile = new FileReference();
            loadFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelectHandler);
            var fileFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images: (*.jpeg, *.jpg, *.gif, *.png)", "*.jpeg; *.jpg; *.gif; *.png");
            loadFile.browse([fileFilter]);
        }

        protected function fileSelectHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            loadFile.load();
            urlInput.text = event.target.name;
        }
        public function addButtonClickEvent(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (urlInput.text.length == 0)
            {
                var num:int = gender.selectedIndex;
                var img:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost/demo/images/image.jpg");
                var loader:Loader = new Loader();
                loader.load(url);
                if (num == 0)
                {

                    urlInput.text = "male.jpg";
                    img = url.data; 
                }
            } 
            else
            {
                img = loadFile.data;
            }
            empDetails.addItem({
                name : nameInput.text,
                image : img
            });
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Form id="addForm">
    <s:FormItem id="nameLabel" label="Name">
        <s:TextInput  id="nameInput"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem id="urlLabel" label="Employee Image:">
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:TextInput id="urlInput" editable="false"/>
            <s:Button id="browseButton" label="Browse" click="browseButtonClickHandler(event)"/>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Button id="addButton" label="Add" click="addButtonClickEvent(event)"/>
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
```

Here, I have to add the name, and the image into the ArrayCollection for future use. If I doesn't select image here, it will throw an exception. But what I need, If I doesn't select image in form, it has to be take this image "image.jpg" as a selected image. But an error is being here like
*Multiple markers at this line:
-1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.utils:ByteArray.
-img*
I don't know how to remove this error. If anybody can find it, Please inform me? or How can I do this task?

Comment: That error is coming from img = url.data or img.loadFile.data. You need to cast the data to a ByteArray.

Comment: Can you explain more or share the code for cast data to ByteArray